How to Automate Environment Setup on Windows Startup for Development?
I'm a React Native developer working on a Windows machine. Every time I start my computer, I need to manually open several applications and run some commands to set up my development environment. This includes:

Starting Docker
Opening Visual Studio Code
Running some commands in the terminal

This process is quite time-consuming and I'd like to automate it so that everything starts up automatically when I log in. I'm looking for a solution that can:

Start Docker and ensure my containers are running
Open Visual Studio Code and possibly load my project
Run specific terminal commands

I've considered using the Windows Startup folder and writing a batch script, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I'm also open to using third-party tools if they can provide a more robust solution.
What's the best way to automate this process? Are there any tools or techniques that developers commonly use for this purpose?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
